# How to create this xml file by using System.Xml

Tags: .net, xml, soap, xml-namespaces

I am trying to create an xml file like below in .NET. Actually I couldnt do `<soap:Header>` part. Just needed that part:

```
<soap:Header>
<AuthenticationSoapHeader
xmlns="http://example.service.com/WS">
<WSUserName>WSusername</WSUserName>
</AuthenticationSoapHeader>
</soap:Header>
```

I can do like below, I need something like above

```
<Header> <AuthenticationSoapHeader
xmlns="http://example.service.com/WS">
<WSUserName>WSusername</WSUserName>
</AuthenticationSoapHeader> </Header>
```

Thanks in advance,

doc = new XmlDocument();

XmlNode header = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"soap","Header","");

Comment: Can you post the way do you use to create the xml? (sample code?) In any case, you sould add the correct namespace that is mapped to the soap prefix to the Header element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML you are trying to create is poorly formed.  The soap namespace prefix has not been declared.

I would be surprised if you can find any DOM library that will allow you to create it.

Comment: I suppose the code shown is only part of a whole XML file with the prefix declared "above". In case it is not, you are totally right and a tool should actually refuse to create such a thing. (Barış, keep in mind that the prefix does not state anything except "my namespace can be looked up under this prefix declared with xmlns:soap="..." on my node or any of my parents", so the prefix without its declaration will be totally useless.